# Sounds from applications are too big, but I can barely hear them

Tags: audio, audio-volume

I was streaming a game, and people said the sound is way too big and distorted. I tried lowering the volume, and they said the volume is not anymore big but still severely clipped.

At first I didn't understand how can small sounds be clipped, so I ran pavucontrol to see that sounds from applications are received way too big, yet I don't hear any sound big enough.

Below the image, I am running two programs that make sounds. I can barely hear anything from sdlmame, and I can hear sounds from Chrome in a proper volume. But the image tells that both sounds from the applications are big enough, or too big for the Chrome one. At least that was what the viewers of my stream were hearing.

[image: the volume indicator shows sounds are big enough.]

When I tried lowering the volume I lowered the volume in 'Output Devices' -> 'Built-in Audio Analog Stereo'. Also lowered on from the streaming software.

I tried something to solve this problem, like

- checking the volume setting from alsamixer. The settings were the same from when my audio output worked properly.
- removing entire pulseaudio and alsa-lib/utils/plugins and reinstalling them. I tried with `sudo pacman -Rdd` to remove.
- I could have a proper volume when I plugged earphones in. I could hear at the level close enough to what the volume indicators in pavucontrol shows. I could raise the output volume up and the value in indicators didn't change. So I tried without earphones, and I had to raise the output volume over 100%, which increases the values in the indicators too, which might means that the sounds being sent through the streaming software would get clipped and distorted.

`lspci -v | grep -i audio` says I have:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

`alsamixer` says I have:

```
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Realtek Generic
```

`cat /proc/asound/version` says I have:

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.11.9-1-ARCH.
```

I want to fix this audio problem. When I am hearing okay, other people hears bad audio. When other people seem to hear okay, I barely hear anything from my computer. Applications in my computer sends way too big sounds and I don't hear them big enough.